# How to find the current location of the program break

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, sbrk, brk

I tried adding this inside the brk system call function :

```
void *addr = sbrk(0);
printk("current-add-is-%p-\n", addr);
```

But it returned error during kernel compilation that implicit declaration of sbrk function. And I could not find where sbrk is defined!!
All I need to measure that whenever some user process tries to extended its program break address, I would know its current program break address, so that I can measure how much memory processes are requesting.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to do something wrong.

There is no 'sbrk' syscall, there is 'brk'. Except then it would be named sys_brk, but you have no reasons to call it. So if you want to find out how to learn the current break address, read brk's sources.

However, where exactly did you put this in if you did not happen to find brk's sources?

Comment: Could you please tell what do you mean by "read brk's sources" put this in brk system call method. I understand there is no sbrk system call. But man page of sbrk says sbrk(0) will give the current program break address , so just tried sbrk(0)

Comment: @ArjunBora: Man pages describe functions, available for **user space** programs. *Kernel space* code operates with *different* functions set.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Okay, so is there any way I can find the current program break address from the kernel space ? equivalent of sbrk(0) Thanks.

Comment: @ArjunBora: As the answerer said, you may look into `brk` syscall implementation - this is how `sbrk()` is actually implemented. Probably, you will be able to reuse parts of its code for perform needed task (getting  current break address). For searching syscall implementation you may use `grep -r . --include "*.c" -e "SYSCALL_DEFINE1(brk"` in the top-level directory with kernel sources.

Comment: @ArjunBora: the current task's break address should be in `current->mm->brk`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code:

```
printf("Address of program break is %p\n", (void *)sbrk(0));
```

It will return a message to terminal with hex address of the program break.(e.g., 0x#### #### ####.)

If you want the address in other than hex, then use **%u** or similar. The use of `sbrk(0)` is documented in man pages (linux programmers manual).

To see documentation, type in command line:  `man sbrk` and documentation will pop up.